# Is it possible to view all recent comments?

Tags: support, comments, moderator-tools

Is it possible to view all recent comments?

I want to review all the recent comments posted to a site.

- Sorted chronologically
- All users (every/any user together)
- Including the user's name and the comment's text/body

Something [approximately like this view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/139866/chrisw?tab=activity&sort=comments) except for all/any users.

Is this available as a standard view, a "stack-app", or anything else?

Most people aren't too interested in comments: but this feature might help moderate a site, to see comments (conversations) which are being posted by any user even on old questions or answers.

Comment: <insert 'comments are second class citizens' rant here>

Comment: Only via the Data Explorer, comments posted until last Sunday-ish.

Comment: SEDE is kind of late (not real-time) for effective moderation purposes.

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments

Comment: The link isn't hard to construct: <post link>#comment<comment id>_<post id>

Comment: @yannis Yea, one could simply find the latest number in use and iterate over the X before that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://charcoal-se.org/blaze/ will do this. (Unfortunately, you can't bookmark the comments view, so you have to fill out the form every time you visit.)

[Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/questions/4941/blaze-for-finding-and-flagging-low-quality-posts)

Answer (score 3):

As @yannis noted in the comments, it's possible with the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). You'd need to tweak the output a bit by modifying the [default filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), but I believe this URL should work quite well (subsitute the `site` parameter with the site you're interested in):

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#order=desc&pageSize=100&sort=creation&filter=!1zSsiTYsgwRn4To5dvUwR&site=buddhism&run=true

[image]

The benefit of the documentation page (instead of the 'raw' API endpoint) is that it automatically generates links to the comment (and the user) and a hover option for the comment date. The downside is that long comments require some scrolling to read; for those, the [direct link](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments?order=desc&sort=creation&site=buddhism&filter=!1zSsiTYsgwRn4To5dvUwR) might work better. The direct link is available from the 'address bar' above the output.

[image]

Note that HTML entities are still escaped, but in most cases that shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: I use https://charcoal-se.org/blaze/

Comment: Sure, this is just an alternative if Blaze is down.